# Allow Documentation in other Stack Exchange communities

Tags: feature-request, documentation-beta

I'm a Salesforce developer and would love Documentation to be available in other Stack Exchange communities. The reason is [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) a lot of Salesforce developers get help, especially newer ones like myself. The developer forums and documentation on [developer.salesforce.com](http://developer.salesforce.com) is mediocre. It would be nice to allow users to create their own and give pack on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If/when this feature does make it to other sites in the future, it's going to be very far off in the future. Expanding to other sites is not something we are even thinking about at this particular moment in time.

Comment: @animuson How about allowing non-SO sites to propose tags that could be  allowed on the SO documentation platform, which would otherwise be rejected because too few of the questions are on SO itself? I'm thinking things like, for example, [ArcPy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) (Python-based GIS, [discussed on GIS meta](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4275/23289)) or the [Drupal Views API](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views)

Comment: In principle it's a good idea, but I guess it will take awhile. The rep system is quite broken and may be very complicated to fix and the quality of the content is also not very high and there are still glitches in the user interface. But if all these problems are solved, why not. It actually may work better in other areas because Programming already has good documentation for many years in many areas while other topics might profit from any good documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow Documentation has been discontinued and is no longer under development.

Answer (score 39):

First off, thanks for asking this. Multiple users have asked on several SE sites, in the comments, and in chat but getting an answer in one place is much needed.

We'd love to roll this out network-wide, but we've been in public beta for less than a week, and the product isn't quite ready to go elsewhere. We are actively iterating on docs by [fixing bugs and making improvements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th).  Once it is [known to work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta#comment369176_328405), then we can discuss the possibility of adding it to other sites but that won't be for [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

In the meantime, feel free to participate in the [Salesforce Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce/topics) and remember [patience you must have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiMxL.jpg).

Comment: It's been 4 months now and much has improved on SO's Docs. Any changes on this position now?

Comment: @user1306322 considering it's still in beta, there has been no change in position.

Comment: @fi12 it's still in beta so probably not

Comment: There is a new Q&A on [meta.gis.se] where the desire for a separate GIS Documentation site has been tagged as a feature request.

Comment: It's been 8 months now. Any changes?

Comment: @haykam Docs is still in beta, and I don't believe it's ready to roll out to other sites.

Comment: Hmm. Let's wait another 4 months then.

Comment: How about now? Any plans to rollout to other sites?

Answer (score 3):

As [just has been announced on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/4751173), Stack Overflow Documentation will be frozen.

This means it also won't be rolled out to other sites in the Stack Exchange network.